# Python video stream to C++ server

Tags: python, c++, sockets, opencv, tcp

I am working to learn C++ through a project where I stream video from one device to display on another. I have a PiCamera with the following client code that captures frames and sends them via TCP stream.

```
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import picamera


def stream():
    servver_ip = "0.0.0.0" #intentionally left out
    client_socket = socket.socket()
    client_socket.connect((server_ip, 8123))
    connection = client_socket.makefile("wb") 

    try:
        camera = picamera.PiCamera()
        camera.resolution = (640, 480)
        camera.start_preview()
        time.sleep(2)
        start = time.time()
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        for image in camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg'):
            connection.write(struct.pack("<L", stream.tell()))
            connection.flush()
            stream.seek(0)
            connection.write(stream.read()) 
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()
        connection.write(struct.pack("<L", 0)) 
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    finally:
        connection.close()
        client_socket.close()

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            stream()
        except ConnectionRefusedError as e:
            print("Connection refused. It the server on?")
            time.sleep(2)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code above comes directly from a PiCamera recipie and works great when I have a Python script on the other end. However, when I attempt to receive and display the stream with the following C++ code I get only partial frames and it doesn't flow well at all. Sometimes I get 0 data, 1 frame, or a slow choppy mess. Changing the usleep increment seems to get some improvement but I fear it's not the correct answer. I've also tried using the MSG_WAITALL flag in recv but that seems to keep any data from coming through which might suggest I have an incorrect value for my buffer size.

```
// the standard stuff
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

// opencv
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>

//socket stuffs
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int key;

    int yes = 1;

    int height = 480;
    int width = 640;

    char* listenPort = "8123";

    int bytes = 0;

    int status;
    struct addrinfo hints; // define our interface
    struct addrinfo *serviceinfo; // will point to results
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints)); // make sure the struct is empy
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // don't care if IP4 or IP6
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // fill in my IP for me

    // look up address info for this machine. Will populate service info
    if ((getaddrinfo(NULL, listenPort, &hints, &serviceinfo)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    // make the socket
    int sockfd = socket(serviceinfo->ai_family, serviceinfo->ai_socktype, serviceinfo->ai_protocol);

    //bind to the correct port
    if ((bind(sockfd, serviceinfo->ai_addr, serviceinfo->ai_addrlen)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to bind: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    // allow us to reuse the port
    if ((setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes))) == -1){
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }

    // number of connections to let in the queue
    int backlog = 1;

    // start listening for incoming connections
    if ((listen(sockfd, backlog)) == -1){
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    // start accepting incoming connections
    socklen_t addr_size = sizeof(their_addr);
    int new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size); // use this for all send and receive calls
    if (new_fd == -1){
        perror("accept");
        exit(1);
    }

    // empty image object
    cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC1);

    if (!img.isContinuous()){
        img = img.clone();
    }

    int image_size = img.total() * img.elemSize();

    cv::Mat rawImage = cv::Mat::zeros(1, image_size, CV_8UC1);

    if (!rawImage.isContinuous()){
        rawImage = rawImage.clone();
    }
    cv::Mat flipped = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC1);

    std::cout << "Press q to quit" << std::endl;
    cv::namedWindow("Sentry", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (key != 'q'){
        std::cout << "Capturing" << std::endl;

        if ((bytes = recv(new_fd, rawImage.data, image_size, 0)) == -1){
            perror("Failed to receive bytes!");
            exit(1);
        }

        img = cv::imdecode(rawImage, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        cv::flip(img, flipped, 1);


        if (flipped.data != NULL) {
            // show image. using a global here
            cv::imshow("Sentry", flipped);
        }

        memset(rawImage.data, 0x0, sizeof(rawImage));

        // look for quit key
        key = cv::waitKey(10);

        // pause for half a second
        usleep(500000);
    };

    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    freeaddrinfo(serviceinfo); // clear the linked list

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;

}
```

I'm looking for any tips, answers or just to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Working solution**
First, thanks Kevin for helping me out. My issue was I did not realize my initial Python client was sending the image size. Doing some searching and working with the answers below I started grabbing those first 4 bytes and began resizing my `cv::Mat rawImage`. Instead of writing the logic to check `recv` to ensure I'm getting all the data, I'm using `MSG_WAITALL`. That flag in combination with getting the correct payload size got everything working smoothly. Very humbling experience.

```
#define CHUNKSIZE 500

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // skipping code from before

    int32_t image_size = 0;
    cv::Mat rawImage;
    long data_received = 0;
    long success;

    cv::namedWindow("Sentry", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (key != 'q'){
        std::cout << "Capturing" << std::endl;

        // Very important!! Grab the image_size here
        success = recv(new_fd, &image_size, 4 , NULL);
        if (success == -1){
            perror("Failed to receive file size!");
            exit(1);
        }
        // if your image size is extremely large, it's probably 
        // because you're grabing the wrong number of bytes above
        if (image_size > 300000){
            std::cout << "Image size is too large " << image_size << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        if (image_size > 0) {

            //
            rawImage = cv::Mat::zeros(1, image_size, CV_8UC1);
            success = recv(new_fd, rawImage.data, image_size, MSG_WAITALL);
            if (success == -1){
                perror("Failed to receive");
                exit(1);
            }

            img = cv::imdecode(rawImage, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

            if (img.data != NULL) {
                // show image. using a global here
                cv::imshow("Sentry", img);
            } else {
                std::cout << "Image is null!" << std::endl;
            }

            memset(&rawImage, 0x0, sizeof(rawImage));

            // look for quit key
            key = cv::waitKey(10);
        } else {
            std::cout << "No message yet" << std::endl;

        }
        image_size = 0;
        // pause for half a second
        usleep(500000);
    };

    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    freeaddrinfo(serviceinfo); // clear the linked list

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had this same problem when I created a live stream Raspberry Pi to my PC using wifi with C++.

I solved it by only sending chunks of image. Test the chunks at around 500 bytes then increase it once you see its working. Dont send the entire file or else the program will only get part of the frame.

Also, dont read the return code of send() or recv() functions as @Sam stated, I have actually found it to be unreliable when creating a live stream. Just send it in chunks and it should be okay.

I have my source code if you want to take a look it at, I know its very hard to create a live stream server using C++ because there is almost no documentation, so I want to help you out since it gave me sooo much head aches! Let me know if you want the source good luck!

Client should look something like this, this wont compile! I tried to make it easily readable:

```
//Client    
#define CHUNK_SIZE 500

int main()
{
    //do all the connection stuff here and connect to it
    int filesize;
    int dataReceived = 0;
    char received_message[10];
    std::vector<char> imageData;
    while (1)
    {
        recv(Connection, received_message, 11, NULL); //recieved File size of image
        filesize = atoi(received_message); //Turning File size char into an integer 

        imageData.resize(filesize); //Setting up vector to recieve image data

        while (dataReceived < filesize) //keep running until we get enough bytes
        {
            if (filesize - dataReceived >= CHUNK_SIZE) //if the amount of bytes left to recieve is greater than or equal to chunk size, then lets receive a CHUNK_SIZE of the image
            {
                recv(Connection, &imageData[dataReceived], CHUNK_SIZE, 0);
                dataReceived += CHUNK_SIZE;
            }
            else //Else, if the amount of bytes left to recieve is smaller than the CHUNK_SIZE then lets receive a specific amount of bytes
            {
                recv(Connection, &imageData[dataReceived], fileSize - dataReceived, 0);
                dataReceived += fileSize - dataReceived;
            }
         Sleep(Amount of sleep); //Note, python code will always be slower than C++ so you must set a Sleep() function.
        }
        std::cout << "Got the image, it is stored in the imageData vector!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press enter to get another image!" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you just chunk the `sockstream` like I've got in the client code above?

Comment: @Andrew No, I forgot to mention that you have the send the file size first! Send the file size to C++ then break it off into chunks. Im going to edit my answer so you can see what I am talking about give me a sec

Comment: @Andrew updated some crucial stuff in the code I forgot to add

Comment: thanks for the code sample. I am trying very hard to understand what you have here. What is `&fileData[dataReceived]` supposed to be? Shoud that be `imageData` or another buffer?

Comment: @Andrew yes it was a typo, sorry about that! fileData is supposed to be imageData. I fixed it

Comment: @Keving_Duarte Thanks, this helped a lot! Unfortunately I'm on to the next error "Corrupt JPEG"

Comment: @Andrew check if the file size is the same from the C++ application and the Python application. Would you like to see my source code? Its fully working and has latency less than a second, im sure you could be able to use parts of the code to see where you are getting screwed up on

Comment: @Kevin_Duarte I got it working. Thanks for your help! One major difference is checking the file size and ensuring I'm only taking the first 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The shown code mostly ignores the return value from `recv()`.

```
if ((bytes = recv(new_fd, rawImage.data, image_size, 0)) == -1){
```

It is true that an error results in `recv()` returning -1.

But if `recv()` did not return -1, it doesn't mean that `recv()` has read `image_size` bytes, here.

But the shown code now appears to assume that the entire image has been read, `image_size` bytes. This is a false assumption. When it comes to network sockets, if the receiver has, to date, received fewer bytes, `recv()` will immediately return.

A positive return value from `recv()` indicates how many bytes were actually received and placed into the buffer. If this is fewer bytes than you expected, you are responsible for calling `recv()` again. Note that you can't just

```
recv(new_fd, rawImage.data, image_size, 0)
```

again, because the initial part of `rawImage.data` already contains however many bytes were received by the first call to `recv()`. You will need to work out some simple logic, here, to read the rest of it (keeping in mind that the second call to `recv()` isn't guaranteed to read the rest of it, either).

Comment: Hi, can you please reopen my this edited question . I changed my question completely that I posted one month ago. I can't ask new questions.improving existing one .help please http://stackoverflow.com/q/41820728/6789999

Comment: So if I just put the recv in a while loop and break when bytes=0 will that assign data to the buffer sequentially ?

Comment: No. Reread what I wrote. Whatever buffer pointer you pass to `recv()`, that's where `recv()` will place any received data. Full stop.`recv()` has no magical knowledge that you already called `recv()` with a pointer to the same buffer before, so it should place any additional data received into the buffer after the previously-`recv()`ed data. If, when you called `recv()`, you got fewer than expected, it is your responsibility to recall `recv()` with a pointer reset to point after the data that's now been received, and a count of how many bytes ***left*** there is to receive.